# Angularjs "ng-repeat" filter over and over, it filters out the entire array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is an ever increasing array variable. Whenever a new element is added, the filter is triggered. Array filters all elements. Since the array I repeat contains real time data, continuous data is added. This is causing performance loss. As the size of the array grows, the filter starts to fail.

```
ng-repeat="data in col.columnData
                  | filter:{body:col.UIFilter.match}
                  | filter:repostQuery(col.UIFilter.repost)
                  | filter:mediaQuery(col.UIFilter.media)
                  | orderBy:'iPostedTime':'+'
                  | limitTo:col.columnSettingsObject.listLimit
                  track by data.id"
```

(ARRAY SIZE > ~1000}

What needs to be done is to filter the added element after the filter has been applied, rather than the entire index when the element is added. How can I do that?

Comment: This is the Angular approach, it listens to array changes and knows it has to reapply filter on change but still takes whole array. You can separate old and new elements into 2 different arrays, filter starting array once and filter added elements separately in different array continuously. THen merge both arrays and display that with ng-repeat without filters. This is quite hackish but it will work. AngularJS is generally convention over configuration framework and this is one of the downsides when something does not fit the convention it has to be worked around and it's often not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't append so many filter. Also you shouldn't use filter on big datasets because the filter will add a watcher for every entry.

5 filter 1000 entry = 5000 watchers = extremely slow

You should aim for only 200 watchers per site and a digest cycle of max 2ms, The best approach would be to filter the data before you insert it into `col.columnData`.
You can achive this with:

```
let temp = your_original_dataset;
temp = $filter('filter')(temp, {body:col.UIFilter.match});
temp = $filter('filter')(temp, repostQuery(col.UIFilter.repost));
temp = $filter('filter')(temp, mediaQuery(col.UIFilter.media));
temp = $filter('orderBy')(temp, 'iPostedTime', '+');
temp = $filter('limitTo')(temp, col.columnSettingsObject.listLimit);
col.columnData = temp;

ng-repeat="data in col.columnData track by data.id"
```

**BEWARE** this isn't tested. I don't know the exact writing for $filter just look it up. 
Hope this helps